# Is it possible to compile a C/C++ source code that executes in all Linux distributions without recompilation?

Tags: c++, c, linux

Is it possible to compile a C/C++ source code that executes in all Linux distributions without recompilation?

If the answer is yes, can I use any external (non-standard C/C++) libraries?

I want distribute my binary application instead of distribute of source code.

Comment: Since some linux distributions target different architectures such as arm and some are x86_64 and some are even more obscure that puts up a *really* big hurdle right from the start.

Comment: When you say "all Linux distributions" how far back are you looking?

Comment: you should statically compile all libraries in the executable and that would be already a step in the right direction, as that is what usually breaks stuff from running in different environment. but different architectures remains an issue.

Comment: @jancha - even with statically linked programs there are problems still, for example changes in system calls

Comment: so if one wants universal thing, then java is one of solutions for that.

Comment: @jancha: if you deliver the source files and Makefiles, you should be able to build on most distributions, as long as you restrict yourself to operations defined in the C and C++ Standards. Linux distributions usually come with gcc out of the box.

Comment: I think authors point is to hide source from end users, thus asking for multi-platform binary. but sure, source files are also common way of tackling the issue.

Comment: An alternate solution is to run the source code through a code obfuscator.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No, you can't compile an executable the executes in all Linux distributions. However, you can compile an executable that works on most distributions that people will tend to care about.

1. Compile 32-bit. Compile for the minimum CPU level you're willing to support.
2. Build your own version of glibc. Use the `--enable-kernel` option to set the minimum kernel version you're willing to support.
3. Compile all other libraries you plan to use yourself. Use the headers from your glibc build and your chosen CPU/compiler flags.
4. Link statically.
5. For anything you couldn't link to statically (for example, if you need access to the system's default name resolution or you need PAM), you have to design your own helper process and API. Release the source to the helper process and let them (or your installer) compile it.
6. Test thoroughly on all the platforms you need to support.

You may need to tweak some libraries if they call functions that cannot work with this mechanism. That includes `dlopen`, `gethostbyname`, `iconv_open`, and so on. (These kinds of functions fundamentally rely on dynamic linking. See step 5 above. You will get a warning when you link for these.)

Also, time zones tend to break if you're not careful because your code may not understand the system's zone format or zone file locations. (You will get no warning for these. It just won't work.)

Most people who do this are building with the minimum supported CPU being a Pentium 4 and the minimum supported kernel version being 2.6.0.

Comment: This answer is a few years out of date. You can distribute a 64-bit build now. You don't need to link statically -- you can include shared libraries. And you probably don't need to compile your own version of glibc. The typical minimum CPU is now any 64-bit capable CPU, and the typical minimum supported kernel version is higher.

Comment: how can you use shared libraries that might not be present on the target machine? Unless you actually distribute the shared libraries along with your binary - which would defeat the purpose

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I recommend linking statically. (Or at least, I did in 2011 or so.) See 4 and 5 above.

Comment: Doh! I hadn't noticed that you were the the same person - that you were commenting on your own answer. So I assumed you were disagreeing with the answer, not merely updating it. I guess your points (3) and (5) are basically saying that we need to bundle all necessary software together for distribution to users. But it doesn't need to be statically linked together

Answer (score 4):

There are two differences which are among installations. Architecture and libraries.

1. Having one binary for different architectures is not directly possible; there was an attempt to have binary for multiple archs in one file ([fatelf](http://icculus.org/fatelf/)), but it is not widely used and unlikely to gain momentum. So at least you have to distribute separate binaries for ia32, amd64, arm, ... (most if not all amd64 distros have kernel compiled with support for running ia32 code, though)
2. Distributions contain different versions of libraries. You're fine as long as the API does not change, you can link to that library. Some libs ensure inary backwards-compatibility within major number (so GTK2.2 app will run fine with GTK2.30 lib, but not necessarily vice versa). If you want to be sure, you have to link statically with all libs that you use, except the most basic ones (probably only `libc6`, which is binary-compatible accross distros AFAIK). This can increase size of the binary, and it one of reasons why e.g. Acrobat Reader is relatively big download, although the app itself is not specially rich functionality-wise.
3. There was a transitional period for c++ ABI, which changed between gcc 2.9 and 3 (IIRC), but the old ABI would be really just on ancient installations. This should no longer be an isse for you, and if you link statically, it is irrelevant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no.

There are several bariers.

**Different architectures**

While a 32bit binary will run on a x86_64 system, it won't work vice versa. Plus there is a lot of ARM systems.

**Kernel ABI**

Kernel ABI changes very slowly, but it does change, therefore you can't really support all possible versions. Note that in some places kernel 2.2 is still in use.

What you can do is to create a statically linked binary. Such binary will include all libraries your app depends on, and it will work on all systems with the same architecture and a reasonably similar kernel version.