# Can glibc be compiled into one object file

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64, glibc

Can `glibc` be compiled into one object file which can then be linked to any program. The main purpose is portability here. Because I don't require to install dynamic libraries this way. Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: I thought a glibc was a library of object files that could be linked into any C program.  Is that not correct?  You can do static or dynamic linking, but by the time you get glibc that decision has been made for you.  Why would your wish be more portable?  Voting to close - this question makes no sense to me as written.

Comment: My question is if its possible to compile it into one consolidated object file rather than separate files.

Comment: It's already compiled.  Still makes no sense at all.

Comment: I don't follow how that would help you. Why would one object file be in any way better than one `ar` archive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile `glibc` to `.a` files which can be linked into a static executable. The static libraries are built by default.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7461214/721269) for some suggestions. Just compiling `glibc` will build the static libraries too.