# clang seems to use the gcc libraries

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

This is the first time I use `clang`. What I notices is that any error from clang referencing the std library looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/ostream:245:7:
                ^^^                  ^^^                         ^^^
```

So it looks like clang links — or at least includes — the gcc libraries.

The command I used: `clang++ -c -Wall -Wextra -Werror -g test.cpp -o test.o`. (The program had a intentional error just to prove this).

How is this possible? What can I do to make `clang` use its own libraries (but not break gcc)?

---

Additional information:

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

```
clang++ --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I had previously installed several versions (at the same time, used them with `update-alternatives`) of `gcc` with `apt-get`. Right now I have only `4.8` (I have uninstalled the others). Could I have messed up something then? I have never installed clang (I guess it is default with Ubuntu).

Just to clarify: the correct programs compile and run in `clang++`.

Further tests: I know that `gcc` didn’t implement yet types like `is_trivially_constructible` and move operations on `iostream` in their standard c++11 library (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html) and that clang has full c++11 conforming library so I tested those compiling with clang and I got the corresponding gcc errors, which only confirms that clang is using gcc libraries.

A very basic program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() { 
  cout << "Yada Yada" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

gives this error when compiling with -std=c++1y in clang++:

```
In file included from /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/iostream:39:
...
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/cstdio:120:11: error: no member named 'gets' in the global namespace
  using ::gets;
        ~~^
```

So right now I can’t compile anything with `c++1y` in clang.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to install `libc++` and make clang use it with `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: I couldn’t install `libc++` (some errors about dependencies). I installed `libc++1` (which looks like it's the c++11 library which is what I want). When I compile with `-stdlib=libc++` I get `fatal error: 'iostream' file not found #include <iostream>`. If I compile with `-stdlib=libc++1` I get  `clang: error: invalid library name in argument '-stdlib=libc++1'`. Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587228/clang-error-stddef-file-not-found I have checked both simlinks and they are both correct, but in the folders linked there are a few headers, but not standard headers

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't no much about Ubuntu, but under Fedora it was easy to build libc++ from source. (Although I got a funny linker error, but that is a different question and already answered on SE).

Comment: @bolov To actually build new programs with it, you need `libc++-dev` (the headers), not just `libc++1` (the library).

Comment: @o11c, if I compile a binary to give to others, will I need to ensure that the users have `libc++1` on their machine? Although, I guess the same question applies to `g++` and `libstdc++`. Do modern Linux distributions install some version of `libstdc++` by default?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid *"Do modern Linux distributions install some version of libstdc++ by default?"* No they don't. You can in general not just ship binaries for Linux. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461152/is-it-possible-to-compile-a-c-c-source-code-that-executes-in-all-linux-distrib

Comment: @AaronMcDaid LSB requires some version of `libstdc++.so.6`, but then you have to worry about which *version* of LSB supports which *version* of `libstdc++.so.6`

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issue: GCC (g++) already was installed on my LinuxMint (Ubuntu base) so when compile with clang, was getting an " error: no member named 'gets' in the global namespace   using ::gets ".

resolved by installing libc++-dev (`sudo apt-get install libc++-dev`) and compiling with -stdlib++ (`clang++ -g -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld`)

Answer (score 9):

Your real problem is that you're using C++14 (c++1y was the informal name used to refer to it when it wasn't yet fully formed), with a C++ library belonging to GCC 4.8. GCC 4.8 has complete C++11 support, but hardly even started on C++14 features.

This is caused by C++14 removing `std::gets`, and the GNU C library anticipating on that by not defining `gets` in the global namespace while the C++ library has not yet caught up and is trying to make it available in the `std` namespace.

The proper way to solve this does not require using libc++, just to use a C++ library with C++14 support. GLIBCXX 4.9 (aka libstdc++) already suffices.

Comment: this is not the real problem. I knew that `libstd++` and `libc++` differ in the stage of implementation for C++11/C++14 standard and I merely used this knowledge to prove which library was used.

Comment: I got this exact error message with the same GCC version (4.8.2) when attempting to build in C++14 mode with Clang 3.8, using GCC 4.9.4's libstdc++ fixes it.

Comment: again: this question is not about fixing the errors. Read the paragraph starting with "Further tests" from my question.